# Mock objects in Junit test gives NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

When I mock objects in Junit test cases using of PowerMock and Mockito, I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/exceptions/base/MockitoSerializationIssue
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got this when combining PowerMock with Mockito. Fixed by using compatible version as shown here: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions

Comment: The link now just points to the powermock github, it should (I think) be updated to this: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions

Answer (score 1):

Check version of your mockito lib.  I see org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoSerializationIssue class in 2.0.2-beta. It is not present in 1.9.5 .

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the beta version. The latest 1.10.x should also work. I had the same problem when using 1.9.5, but changing to 1.10.19 fixed the problem.